# DAC sample rate vs settling time applications

Tags: dac

Trying to understand the trade space on a DAC with a higher sample rate spec versus the longer settling time (same exact part). I'm trying to reconstruct analog waveforms for a DSP application, so there's a bandwidth requirement and a general desire to represent an accurate waveform. Searching around, what I've gathered is that you use the settling time when you "care about the signal settling" and use the sampling rate when you don't, and can live with artifacts. Can someone describe an example situation where you might care about one vs the other? Can the artifacts just be filtered out? Also, I notice that the settling time is defined as either rail to rail or a 10% to 90% spec; Is there an application strategy to limit the output amplitude to improve settling time?

In summary, I believe I understand the concept of the DAC sampling rate vs settling time, but am unsure on how to apply them.

Comment: "what I've gathered is that you use the settling time when you "care about the signal settling" and use the sampling rate when you don't, and can live with artifacts." that is fundamentally wrong, in multiple ways. So I don't think we can explain that misunderstanding.

Comment: You say you do this for DSP purposes; so, I'll assume you're familiar with the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem?

Comment: Please post specifics, like datasheets

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I notice that the settling time is defined as either rail to rail or a 10% to 90% spec;

Those are two definitions of settling time. I've also seen settling to 1%, and to 0.1%, error from final voltage. These are applicable when you are using a DAC as a calibration source, or to fast and coarse tune the VCO in a PLL before final locking. In the latter case, a long tail up to the final value could extend the settling time in an otherwise fast-settling PLL system (ask me how I know!).

Generally we use settling time when the application involves a step to a DC value.

When we want to generate waveforms, we tend to look at the AC parameters, like frequency response, harmonic distortion, spurious products, noise floor, ENOB, SNR etc. The frequency response will probably have quite a strong and simple correlation with the settling time. The other AC parameters not at all.

Generally the maximum sampling rate for a DAC is specified at a rate when the AC parameters are already somewhat degraded from what they could be when you run the DAC at a lower sampling rate. See the graphs in the data sheet for performance versus sample rate.

Generally, sampling rate and settling time are fairly well correlated, though there are exceptions in both directions. There are some DACs with settling times of many samples. There are some, designed for higher alias generation, which have a much shorter settling time than their sample period.

When you want to generate 'exact waveforms', you need to specify exactly what you mean by that, which parts of the waveform count in your application. Then you can decide which of the AC, DC or transient specifications are important for your application.